VMware Workstation 17 Player: 3 monitor layout not working (2 monitor + 1 monitor of the notebook)
I can't use multiple monitor layouts in VMware Workstation Player 17. it works with 2, but not with 3. I press this button, but it does nothing

The solution described in this question does not resolve my problem.
I tried, as suggested there, to use a different theme but without success.
What worked for me was to reinstall VMware tools, but it worked only for one day. The day after, I was again having the same problem.
Does anyone have another solution?
Edit: I saw it's listed as a known issue on the latest release notes so we have to wait

Commenting you also have the same issue isn’t a great comment which is the reason commenting requires a trivial amount of reputation before earning that privilege. What version of VMWare are you running? Have you tried upgrading to Workstation instead of Player? You should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment. How you open a support ticket for VMWare is out of scope here at Super User. Besides, VMWare does not offer technical support, unless you have a paid license.

Thanks for the edit. The exact version of vmware is Workstation 17 Player17.5.2 build-23775571

Why did you submit a comment after being asked to edit your question? You should also try and use Workstation instead of Player.

I was having this problem until just today when I found:
Multiple monitors not working VMware 16 Player
It seems the virtual machine player has some sort of "bug" with the light/dark theme. I swapped from dark theme to the light theme, restarted my VM, then the Unity tool worked with no issues and I was able to swap back to dark theme.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I saw that and tried it, but it didn't work.
I saw it's listed as a known issue on the latest release notes so I guess we just have to wait for a fix... someday

I was having the same problem as you mentioned and by mistake discovered a solution that works with my Ubuntu 20 VM, might work in your case as well.
When modifying multi monitor layout from vmware command bar, the vm would not expand on my monitors as expected so i logged out in ubuntu vm and after login it started working(tried both with ubuntu xorg and ubuntu wayland) both seem to expand to my selected layout after a logout/login.
